# Displaying on view source page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a java Script code which calls an api and returns another javascript code in the form of string. How to display it on view page source and how to call one of it's function.

Comment: The browser's "view page source" option shows the source of the HTML page as it was when originally loaded from the webserver, it doesn't include anything loaded dynamically after that. Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code that retrieves the JS string, and show us a sample of that JS string.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code

Comment: Your question is unclear.... Please add more detail and elaborate what you want and what you have tried.!

Comment: i am calling a api which returns javascript code in the form of string. I want to call one of the function from that returned javascript code

Comment: I am using eval() to convert the response into javascrpit code

Comment: You'll need to use Developer Tools.  Usually found by brining up context menu in browser, then choosing 'Inspect' or 'Inspect Element' off the context menu.  See https://developer.chrome.com/devtools for more information. (and similar for other browsers.) The JS you want should be visible in either Sources, or Network tab (you may need to reload page.)

Comment: Is it possible to display the same js code that i am getting from the api to display on the "view source page"

Comment: How to call one functions in that returned js code -@searlea

Comment: Try to use Ctrl + U to View page Source becasue most of the browser using it. Keyboard shorcuts for every browser are almost the same you can also use Ctrl + Shift + I  to open Developers Tools or Ctrl + Shift + C to Inspect Elements. In addition, try to visit to https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#w_developer-shortcuts learn more on Mozilla Firefox keyboard shorcuts. http://help.opera.com/Windows/9.50/en/keyboard.html for Opera and https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/183101?hl=en for Google Chrome.

Comment: success: function (response) {
            console.log(eval(response));
           

           



        }

Comment: i am able to display the response on console?

Comment: how can i display it on the source page

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Mozilla Firefox** use **Ctrl + Shift + S (Debugger)** or **Shift +F7 (Style Editor)** then select your desired codes to be copy and **Ctrl + S** to save the file or just copy and paste it. For **Opera** use **Ctrl + Shift + C (Inspect Element)** the press the **Sources** tab after element and console. Then you will see that there are different folder that the container of different file or assets that the page use such as images, css, script, and html file. Then select file that you want to copy, you can use **Open link in New Tab** and then save or use **Save As**. For **Google Chrome**, do the same way of the Opera browser.If you are using **Microsoft Edge** or **Internet Explorer** use **F12** then click on **Debugger**, **select on the folder located on the left** and then **copy paste the code** of the slected item.

Comment: "success: function (response) { console.log(eval(response));"
I am using this code to convert my string response to JavaScript Code.
How to call any function from this response

Comment: @Sammy. Please be specific for your question and please provide code with it.

Answer (score 0):

create another script tag using:
$("#body").append(" " + fr + "");
where fr is the string (actually a javascript code)response that i am getting from the api 
and then we can call the function in that response